# Add new Object's name

Tags: javascript

How can I solve the problem typeError?

```html
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid mt-3">
    <p id="result"></p>
  </div>
  <script>
    var peoople, x, message = "";

    function person(first, last, age, color) {
      this.firstName = first;
      this.lastName = last;
      this.age = age;
      this.eyeColor = color;
      this.fullName = function() {
        return this.firstName + " loves " + this.lastName;
      }
    }
    this.changeName = function(name) {
      return this.firstName = name;
    }

    people = new person("Jack", "Barry", 5, "brown");
    people.changeName("some1");



    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = people.firstName;
  </script>
</body>
```

I want to change person "jack" to "some1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this issue occured because of "}" this symbol ^^

so, you should write your code inside of "function person(){}" so the solution is:

```html
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid mt-3">
    <p id="result"></p>
  </div>
  <script>
    var peoople, x, message = "";

    function person(first, last, age, color) {
      this.firstName = first;
      this.lastName = last;
      this.age = age;
      this.eyeColor = color;
      this.fullName = function() {
        return this.firstName + " loves " + this.lastName;
      }
     //} not here
    this.changeName = function(name) {
      return this.firstName = name;
    }
  } // here  

    people = new person("Jack", "Barry", 5, "brown");
    people.changeName("some1");



    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = people.firstName;
  </script>
</body>
```